# Effects coding for deviations from grand mean for every level of variable

Tags: regression, categorical-encoding

Let's say we have a dataset

```
set.seed(42)
x <- data.frame(a = c(rnorm(100,2), rnorm(100,1),rnorm(100,0), rnorm(100,-1)),
                b = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), each = 100))
```

Now, deviation coding (see [link](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/library/r-library-contrast-coding-systems-for-categorical-variables/#DEVIATION)) enables me to see how means of 3 out of 4 levels deviate from the grand mean, and whether this deviation is different from zero (by means of regression analysis). The coding should then look like:

```
|     | A vs g. mean | B vs g. mean | C vs. g. mean |
|-----|--------------|--------------|---------------|
| b_A | 1            | 0            | 0             |
| b_B | 0            | 1            | 0             |
| b_C | 0            | 0            | 1             |
| b_D | -1           | -1           | -1            |
```

How can I code my categorical variable **b** in order to get deviations of all 4 levels of **b** from the grand mean, which would then be the intercept?